# Flex4 List item double click event

Tags: list, actionscript-3, events, apache-flex, flex4

I'm working with a custom List component in flex4. I've created a custom ItemRenderer and everything looks and works as i want, but i'm trying to get the double click event. I'm receiving key down and all other events, but not this one. I've enabled the double click on the List component

```
 doubleClickEnabled="true"
```

and i've added an event listener for

```
ListEvent.ITEM_DOUBLE_CLICK
```

I can click as long as i want, the event just is not triggered.
I could use any advice. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to listen for `MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK` and then you can figure out what was clicked on using `event.target`.

Comment: Thanks. I used this and it works ok. It looks like this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I banged my head on the wall for hours because of this ! Adobe is going backwards with component functionality ! anyway, I found a decent solution :

We're going to add the DOUBLE_CLICK event listener to the dataGroup of the list, which is the container of the items :

```
list.dataGroup.doubleClickEnabled = true;   
list.dataGroup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, handleDoubleClick);
```

Now it works nice, not provoking a double click from the scroller, but sill provoking a double click from an open space (the dataGroup itself) in the list where there are no items. so we only continue the event handler if e.target != dataGroup :

```
private function handleDoubleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  if (list.dataGroup != e.target)
  {
    // double click code
  }
}
```

Now it works fine :) phew ! We shouldn't waste time on this stuff...

---

Bad solution --> DO NOT try to compare e.target's class to the itemRenderer's class of the list, since sometimes e.target is the actual label of the item.